# Customize Content Types In a List

Tags: 2007, content-type, list

I'm working on a SharePoint List that employs multiple Content Types. I would like to add a jQuery floating-draggable DIV containing information specific for each Content Type. I have successfully added such a DIV to a custom NewForm.aspx, however, adding that same functionality to a Content Type has me stumped. Here's my question:

**How can I customize a Content Type with the aforementioned DIV so that each Content Type displays 
information specific to it?**

Thanks in advance for any help with these issues,

Arnold

Comment: Where do you want it to be enabled ? On the DispForm, on the list, on the content type settings ?

Comment: Hi Sebastien,

The DIV needs to be visible when a Content Type is clicked and a NewForm.aspx is displayed with all the base fields plus fields unique to the Content Type. I'm relatively new to SP and so am learning the technical terms.

Thanks,

Arnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, with jQuery, on the selection of the right content type, display the necessary information.  You have two options :

1. You could attach an event to the "New" menu with javascript and jQuery to be able to display your div on the selected of the menu.
2. You could, on the load of the NewForm.aspx page, test which ContentType is selected and show the necessary information.

Would that be enough for you?

Comment: Sebastien,

I'd like to pursue the second option.

When I click New and then a Content Type, in the URL I see a  ContentTypeId, like so: 
 
ContentTypeId=0x01001E6FDB7A46405043BD12AAF7E43E6D1A00C1F2F7A372CFF8478C5413CC1511FE5B

I'm guessing that this would the the string I would need to check. Where in NewForm.aspx do I put this code?

I'm thinking I can place all the DIVs, one for each Content Type in NewForm.aspx. Then when the form is loaded - Document.Ready - make visible the appropriate DIV. Is this more or less what you're suggesting?

Thanks, Arnold

Comment: Exactly! You could create your own NewForm.aspx and then include this code into that new page.